# Gathering info from another window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've spent some time searching, so please excuse me if this is answered someone already.
I've written a program in C# to do various tasks, but rather than gathering info from files I'd like to retrieve a few values from another running program that would be open at the same time as my own software. This other program will have both variables and on-screen data that I need to be placed into variables of my own. Is there a good way to go about this? I know C++ has some methods but I don't know them; so even if I have to write it in C++ and call it through C# I'm fine.

Edit: More infomation; There are 2 message box areas and 3 int variables that I would need to capture the data from during runtime.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what type of controls (edit box, picture ect) in the "other program" you are trying to get values for.

Comment: I would suggest reading about WCF - 
one of the many example tutorial online: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d56e1/how-to-create-and-consume-wcf-services/

when you encounter a specific difficulty you cannot solve, then it is time to ask a question and people here will do their best to answer, currently your post is vague and lacks a real question

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know about WCF until right now. As for vague, I don't appreciate the downvote but there isn't more info to give. There are int variables in the second program that I need found by my program. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to attach to a managed application, you can see how Snoop does this. It is open source: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

> ... rather than gathering info from files I'd like to ...

Well, rather than any of those approaches you can communicate using standard non-file communication such as [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) (or an alternative with less of a learning curve).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to list all windows.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);
```

You can then get additional information about those windows. For example, here is a [blog post](http://blog.tcx.be/2006/05/getting-list-of-all-open-windows.html) that describes how to get the window titles.